# How to create an array/vector of templated objects

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, vector

I have a template class which is a template as a wrapper for MFC `CWnd` objects.

In the main class I want to have a collection of the controls for a panel, but I don't see how I can create an array of them, since they are obviously derived from different base classes (i.e. CButtonCtrl, CListBox, etc.).

```
template<typename W>
class Component : public W
{
public:
    Component(uint_t nId = -1, CWnd *pParent = NULL, const char *pName = NULL)
        : mParent(pParent)
        , mName(pName)
        , mId(nId)
    {
        //std::cout << ((mName != NULL) ? mName : "NULL") << ": " << (void *)this << ": Id:" << mId << " Parent:" << (void *)mParent << std::endl;
    }

    const char *getName(void) const { return mName; }

    void setId(uint_t nId) { mId = nId; }
    uint_t getId(void) const { return mId; }

    void setParent(CWnd *pParent) { mParent = pParent; }
    CWnd *getParent() const { return mParent; }

private:
    uint_t mId;
    CWnd *mParent;
    const char *mName;
};
```

The main class:

```
class Panel : public Component<CDialog>
{
public:
    Panel(uint_t nId = -1, CWnd *pParent = NULL, const char *pComponentName = NULL);
    virtual ~Panel(void) {};

    virtual void CreateWnd(CWnd *pParent = NULL);

    template <typename W>
    void addComponent(Component<W> *pComponent)
    {
    }

    template <typename W>
    void removeComponent(Component<W> *pComponent)
    {
    }

    void Show(bool bShow = true) override;

protected:
    typedef std::vector<Component<?> *> Components;

private:
    Components mComponents;
};
```

In Java there is a syntax for unknown generics like this `Component<?>` so I could store a collection of common objects in an array, but I'm not aware on how to do this in C++. I know that I have to use pointer because of slcing, but that is not the problem here.

Using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: "templated objects" doesn't make much sense. templates apply to types or functions.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try `boost::any` or `std::any`